# I have problem installing freeswitch in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, freeswitch

I tried to install Freeswitch
I did

```
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
```

but when I do

```
make
```

it says

```sh
Entering directory '/usr/src/freeswitch/src/mod/databases/mod_pgsql'
Makefile:958: *** You must install libpq-dev to build mod_pgsql.  Stop.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/freeswitch/src/mod/databases/mod_pgsql'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:714: mod_pgsql-all] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/freeswitch/src/mod'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:615: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/freeswitch/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:3680: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/freeswitch'
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` to install `libpg-dev` and again

```
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make
```

It gives me the same error.

Comment: What command did you try? I don't think that you executed `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`. I think you were installing Freeswitch.. execute that command.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it better.

Comment: Since you have installed the required dependencies, sudo apt-get get update, and try to perform the above steps. If it still doesn't work, reboot and try again.

Comment: which version of ubuntu do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I guess something went wrong.

```sh
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev #for installing libpq-dev
sudo apt-get update            #for updating system
sudo apt-get upgrade           #for upgrading system
sudo chmod +x bootstrap.sh     #make the bash file executable
sudo chmod +x configure        #make the bash file executable
./bootstrap.sh                 #run bootstrap
./configure                    #run configure
make
```

I don't know what does `make` do. So, I just wrote as you wrote.